# EF code first mapping table with 2 FK's from same class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a Friendship mapping table that has 2 FK's that originate from the same class (User). On Add-Migration I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'GameAPI.Models.UserFriendMap' and 'GameAPI.Models.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Here are my two model classes.

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserFriendMap> Friendships { get; set; }
}

public class UserFriendMap
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int FriendID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID"), InversePropertyAttribute("Friendships")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FriendID"), InversePropertyAttribute("Friendships")]
    public User Friend { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }
}
```

I tried override the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendMap>()
        .HasKey(m => new { m.UserID, m.FriendID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendMap>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.UserID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendMap>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.Friend)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.FriendID);

}
```

This causes a new error message to be displayed.

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'GameAPI.Models.UserFriendMap_User' was not loaded because the type 'GameAPI.Models.User' is not available.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The duplicate solution to this question doesn't really achieve the same thing. I want to model the relationship as a separate entity in the DB and a separate model class because the relationship itself is going to grow past just a Friendship date.

Comment: You're right. And, unexpectedly, I couldn't find a better duplicate. So I decided to take a deeper look, and added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always try to approach such problems "bottom up", i.e. first try the class model without any mapping (fluent nor data annotations):

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAssociation> Associations { get; set; }
}

public class UserAssociation
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int FriendID { get; set; }

    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User Friend { get; set; }
}
```

(Using the more neutral name `UserAssociation`).

That quickly failed because there was no key defined for `UserAssociation`. So I added the key annotations:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int UserID { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
public int FriendID { get; set; }
```

Now the model was created, but `UserID` and `FriendID` were not used as foreign key. Instead, EF had added two foreign key fields itself. Not good. So I added foreign key instructions:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
[ForeignKey("User"), InverseProperty("Associations")]
public int UserID { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
[ForeignKey("Friend"), InverseProperty("Associations")]
public int FriendID { get; set; }
```

This caused an exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint ... may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

This is because both foreign keys are created with cascaded delete. SQL Server just doesn't allow two cascading foreign keys in one table. Preventing cascading delete can only be done by fluent mapping, so I **removed all annotations** (I don't like to mix fluent mapping and annotations) and added these mappings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Associations)
                .WithRequired(a => a.User).HasForeignKey(a => a.UserID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Associations)
                .WithRequired(a => a.Friend).HasForeignKey(a => a.FriendID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserAssociation>()
                .HasKey(a => new {a.UserID, a.FriendID});
}
```

Now it was bingo. As you see, you were close, but you started the fluent mappings from the association's side. Also, you had `WithMany()` in stead of `WithMany(u => u.Associations)`). However, using mappings like that I couldn't get it working (somehow, EF didn't seem to know the `User` class in time).

Another point is that when adding data, EF only accepted new `UserAssociation` if the were added to their corresponding `DbSet` of the context, not if they were added to `User.Associations`. Also, when creating an association between existing users, I had to set the primitive foreign key values in the new `UserAssociation`. Setting the object references resulted in

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.

Which doesn't make sense, because `UserAssociation` does expose these key properties.

So it looks like with these self-referencing many to many associations with an explicit junction class we're only barely dodging all kinds of issues EF has in store. Doesn't feel good.

Comment: This all seems a little strange. Following your answer I get the following error:
`Sequence contains no matching element`

Comment: I managed to get this to work. EF didn't like that my inverse relationship was called `Friendships`. Renaming this to anything else built the model correctly. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to your problem but you need to modify your model. To create the friend relationship I create a Friend class that inherit of User. In this class is where I declare the property FriendshipTime, you don't need to declare an Id for it, it uses the Id of User. Now, in User you should have a collection of Friend.

```
public class User
{  
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friend> Friendships { get; set; }
}

public class Friend:User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID"), InversePropertyAttribute("Friendships")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }
}
```

With this model you can do something like this:

```
 var user = new User()
          {
            Username = "User1",
            Friendships = new List<Friend>() { new Friend() { Username ="User2", FriendshipDate = DateTime.Now }, new Friend() { Username = "User3", FriendshipDate = DateTime.Now } }
          };
```

Other aclaration that I want to do is in the case where the Key field is an Integer, Code First defaults to DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity. With a Guid, you need to explicitly
configure this. These are the only types that you can configure to be
Identity when Code First is generating the database

Comment: This solution works but it does not really achieve what I want. I want to model that friendship in its own DB table and have a Model class that represents this relationship. This solution adds the friend relationship to the User table. Is there no way to achieve what I want with the model similar to what I posted above?